# Dragging in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Is there a way to prevent a UIWebView from being dragged?
Also, is there a way to actually overwride the common UIWebView functions such as highlighting?

Hope someone can answer me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the scrollView of the webView and disable the scrolling with this code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;
for(UIView *aView in webView.subviews){
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        scrollView = (UIScrollView *)aView;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        scrollView.bounces = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To prevent the drag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   document.ontouchmove = function(e) 
   {
          e.preventDefault(); 
   }

</script>
```

**To override the highlighting:**

```
<style type="text/css">

    body
    {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    }

</style>
```

So, on the highlighting part:

- The 1st line disables selection (like on text)
- The 2nd line disables the actual highlight
- The 3rd option disables the "popup" you see when you press an image for 2 seconds, asking if you'd like to download/save

Keep the ones you need.

Hope this helps :)